# I couldn't boot the Linux kernel with my new U-Boot environment variable

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, u-boot

Use the following command to start the kernel:

```
setenv bootnet 'tftp 80800000 zImage;tftp 83000000 xxx.dtb'
saveenv
run bootnet
bootz 80800000 - 83000000
```

But using the following command will stop at the Starting Kernel:

```
setenv bootnet 'tftp 80800000 zImage; tftp 83000000 xxx.dtb; bootz 80800000 - 83000000’
saveenv
run bootnet
```

[This is the console output that can be started normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xVKA.jpg)

[This is the console output that cannot be started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXibY.png)

SoC is Freescale IMX6ULL.

Uboot version is 2016.03.

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate more on why do you expect it to work?

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't understand what you meant, that is, I can't boot the kernel by using the environment variables I defined and including bootz

Comment: At first sight, this may be because by your tftp commands are different, `'tftp 80800000 zImage`  versus `tftp 8080 zImage`.

Comment: Sorry i wrote it wrong i have modified it

Comment: Are you sure you have enough space (`0x02800000`) to satisfy kernel decompression requirements?

Comment: My development board has 500M of DDR3 memory, the address is from 0x80000000

Comment: Assuming that the commands are entered correctly, there should be no difference in execution.  Since you do not show the actual console log (with transfer sizes), nobody knows what you entered.  Did you perform a sanity check by repeating the first version?  BTW you neglect to mention what U-Boot version.  The **tftp** command is deprecated now that the transfer can be either direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I uploaded screenshots of the console that can and can't be started normally

Comment: You are using a 4 year old U-Boot. Is your problem reproducible with the current U-Boot? Which board are using?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I haven't tested the latest version. The development board I use is produced by a Chinese manufacturer. It uses Freescale's IMX6ULL series MCIMX6Y2CVM05AA chip.

Comment: *"command will stop at the Starting Kernel"* -- Your description is misleading/inaccurate.  The abort condition is salient information.  Things to try: (1) Add kernel debugging for verbose uncompression messages. (2) Use a uImage (which has a checksum) instead of zImage to validate download. (3) Perform memory tests (U-Boot has two versions of a memtest).    BTW instead of screen captures, you need to learn how to save the log using the terminal emulation program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry about my problem description, I am working hard on my English，I will try it with the new uboot，I do n’t know why, it ran successfully once yesterday，have a nice day.

Comment: Hello, I tested uboot today. This problem still occurs when using uImage. The terminal shows that a prefetch abort exception is generated. I found that the function cache_disable in the file arch \ arm \ lib \ cache-cp15.c adds a little delay. You can start Linux normally, that is, behind the set_cr (reg & ~ cache_bit) code. I do n’t know why, have a nice day.